# Using dims as array lengths

Tags: arrays, asp-classic

Basically, I'm writing an .asp file to create an HTML table that consists of strings in an array.

I need the array to be dynamic so I could add any number of strings to the array from a text file. What I am having is a problem with creating a dynamic array.

What I've tried so far is:

```
set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set f=fs.OpenTextFile("c:\inetasp\test.txt",1)
dim row 

do Until f.AtEndOfStream = true
    f.Skipline
loop

row=CInt(f.Line) 'my try of making "row" an integer and preventing the error...'
dim results()
results=(row-1) 'The line consisting the error which has something to do with "row"'
f.Close

for i=0 to row-1
    results(i)=f.ReadLine
    Response.Write("Results" & result(i))
next
```

As you can see, I'm trying to use a dim to set the length of the array.

I'm new to classic asp, so I could really use some help.
I'd be delighted to add any specifications if asked for :)

Comment: What you need is the Redim statement https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c850dt17%28v=vs.84%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Dijkgraaf said in a comment, the syntax you're looking for is

```vbs
ReDim results(row-1)
```

However, if all you're doing is writing out the rows as you read them, why do you need to put them in an array?

```vbs
Set fs = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fs.OpenTextFile("c:\inetasp\test.txt",1)
Dim r, i
i = 0
Do Until f.AtEndofStream
    i = i + 1
    r = f.ReadLine
    Response.Write "<p>Result " & i & ": " & r & "</p>"
Loop
f.Close
Set f = Nothing
Set fs = Nothing
```

If you absolutely *do* need the results in an array, the quick & dirty way would be to open the file again after looping through the first time to get its size:

```vbs
Set fs = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fs.OpenTextFile("c:\inetasp\test.txt",1)
Dim r, i
i = -1
Do Until f.AtEndofStream
    i = i + 1
    f.Skipline
Loop
f.Close
If i >= 0 Then Redim r(i)
Set f = fs.OpenTextFile("c:\inetasp\test.txt",1)
i = -1
Do Until f.AtEndOfStream
    i = i + 1
    r(i) = f.ReadLine
Loop
f.Close
Set f = Nothing
Set fs = Nothing
```

But this means you're looping through the text file twice. If it's a large text file, that could be a lot of overhead. You could instead make your best guess at the size of the text file, then do `Redim Preserve` if needed.

```vbs
Set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f=fs.OpenTextFile("c:\inetasp\test.txt",1)
Dim r(), i
Redim r(500) '- use your best guess at the number of lines
i = -1
Do Until f.AtEndofStream
    i = i + 1
    If i > UBound(r) Then
        '- redim has its own overhead, so minimize # of times it's called
        Redim Preserve r(i+50) 
    End If
    r(i) = f.ReadLine
Loop
f.Close
Set f = Nothing
Set fs = Nothing
```

Comment: Depends if that is all the array will be used for.

Comment: ReDim fixed the array problem but now i've got another problem with using a dim as a marker for the space in the array. The loop is in the code i asked about before:
    
    Do Until i=r-1
 results(i)=f.ReadLine
    next

Not sure what to do exactly with this. Getting the usual "Object variable not set" error. Am i just stupid or am i missing some detail about using variables?

Comment: And ill be using the array to import it into javascript

Comment: @KarlKuusik: you're getting "Object variable not set" because you've already closed `f` by the time you get to your `Do Until...` loop.

Comment: @Martha: Oh, that explains a lot. But it also creates a problem for me because I need to read the data from the start of the file and it's giving me the error of "input past end of line". Is there a solution to that? I tried creating another .asp for that but it gives me the same error.

Comment: @KarlKuusik: the quick & dirty solution would be to open the file again. Otherwise, you'll have to figure out a way to do everything in one loop through the file -- i.e. checking the size of the array every time, and if it's not large enough, doing a `Redim Preserve`.

Comment: @Martha The re-opening was my intent with creating another .asp for opening the file again but i still got the error. Then again,  i might be doing something wrong... Could you maybe give me an example for re-opening it?

Comment: @KarlKuusik: I've edited my answer instead of trying to answer in comments. Note that none of the new code is tested, because I don't have access to an asp-enabled server from home.